# Running time of an algorithm containing binary elements for cryptography

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Hey guys sorry I'm new to cs and I'm trying to find the running time of algorithms... could you tell me about the algo given how much time is needed in terms of complexity?  The actual algo I created is the same as below but the sum must be more or equal to 2^(n-2).Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iFcE.png)

Comment: Where are you having problems? Step (1) presumably takes one step, (2) does the assignment to $x_i$ $n$ times, (3) is $n$ steps of multiplication and addition, if you do it cleverly using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method), (4) and (5) are one step each.

Comment: Thank you very much, in step 3 though, I'm confused because of the multiplication with 2. So I thought it would be O(log(n)). If you calculate the coefficients it's constantly multiplied by 2. A, I wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We take only one step for computing each $2^ix_i$ (By using left-shift operation we can compute $2^i$ in constant time). So the complexity of Algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

I suspect you used loop for computing $2^i$, and this incurred your bad result.

PS : sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thank you very much, in step 3 though, I'm confused because of the multiplication with 2. So I thought it would be O(log(n)). If you calculate the coefficients it's constantly multiplied by 2. A, I wrong ??

Comment: @NickParisis. Since the $x_i$ are 0 or 1, your sum can be viewed as a binary number. Suppose you wanted to check whether that sum was greater than or equal to $2^{n-2}$; could you do this quickly by merely looking at the bits? For example, if $n=8$ how quickly could you check that, say $01001001\ge 010000000$?

Comment: @Nick. In step 3, to compute $2^ix_i$ we can use left shift operation that takes constant time like other primitive operations (+,-,*,/), we denote this time by c, each comparison take only one step to be evaluated, so phase 3 takes $n(c+1)$. In phase 2, each random sample take constant time, we denote this time by b, we totally execute $n$ random sample in phase 2, so phase 2 take $nd$.

Comment: So, algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ takes overall $n(c+1) + nb = \mathcal{O}(n)$.